# Select2 doesn't work after I make a jquery append

Tags: jquery, select, append, jquery-select2

```
$(".js-example-tokenizer").select2({
    width: '100%',
    tags: true,
    allowClear: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',']
})

  var nl_gest_cor=0;

  $('.adicionar_gestao_coordenacao').click(function() {
  $(".js-example-tokenizer").select2('destroy');
  nl_gest_cor++;
  $("#tabela_gestao_coordenacao").append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="gestao_coordenacao_funcoes'+nl_gest_cor+'"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="gestao_coordenacao_nome'+nl_gest_cor+'"></td><td><select name="select_areas_gestao_coordenacao'+nl_gest_cor+'" id="select_areas_gestao_coordenacao'+nl_gest_cor+'" class="form-control js-example-tokenizer" multiple="multiple"><?php foreach ($areas_educacao as $area){echo '<option value="'.$area['id_areaeducacao'].'">'.$area['cod'].' - '.$area['designacao'].'</option>';}?></select></td></tr>');
  $(".js-example-tokenizer").select2({
    width: '100%',
    tags: true,
    allowClear: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',']
});
```

So I've read in the internet that you have to destroy select2 and after the append initialize it again, however, I've tried this method and still doesnt work, and even throws this error on the console `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function`. It basically shows as a normal select.